# How to enable realtime search in Solr 4.0

Tags: solr, full-text-search, real-time, near-real-time

I’m trying to enable realtime search in Solr 4.0 (So I can see new documents without committing).

I’ve added:

```
<realtime visible="0" facet="true">true</realtime>
```

But documents aren’t seen before commit (or softCommit).
Any help will be appreciated.

- I believe this feature is only available in Solr RA but any information on how to achieve it will be great.

Thanks,
    Avner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as my understanding this can't be done in Solr 4.0 but only in Solr-ra http://solr-ra.tgels.com
Solr 4.0 has the soft commit feature which helps with NRT search requirements.
It has a new feature which supports the get operation without commit by enabling logged update but without the search capabilities.